# I want books about unitriangular matrix groups .

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, reference-request

My motivation to ask for references for unitriangular matrix group is:

I was searching for groups of order $27$ and I found one type of them up to isomorphism is unitriangular matrix group Unitriangular matrix group: $UT(3,3)$.

So, I want to learn more about these groups in general.